# AssertionError while training mnist dataset using theano and keras

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, keras

I was doing a tutorial on deep learning and there was mnist dataset classification example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10 # number of classes

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

(X_train, y_train) , (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# reshape data
X_train =  X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols) # 1 is 1 channnel i.e. grayscale
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")

# normalization
X_train /= 255;
X_test /= 255;

print("X_train shape: ", X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], " train samples")
print(X_test.shape[0], " test samples")

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
print("One hot encoding: {}".format(y_train[0, :]))

model = Sequential();

model.add(Convolution2D(6, 5, 5, input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols), border_mode = "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode= "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(120, 5, 5, border_mode= "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10)) # because 10 output classes
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# TRAIN
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adadelta")
nb_epoch = 2

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch, show_accuracy= True, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 0)
print("Test score: ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy: ", score[1])
```

However, on the line:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch, show_accuracy= True, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
```

I get an exception, "AssertionError was unhandled by user code". I get no other message in the exception.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Somehow you're not getting error messages properly. But this line `y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)` is clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you, now it works :)

Comment: @y300: Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10 # number of classes

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

(X_train, y_train) , (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# reshape data
X_train =  X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols) # 1 is 1 channnel i.e. grayscale
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")

# normalization
X_train /= 255;
X_test /= 255;

print("X_train shape: ", X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], " train samples")
print(X_test.shape[0], " test samples")

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)
print("One hot encoding: {}".format(y_train[0, :]))

model = Sequential();

model.add(Convolution2D(6, 5, 5, input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols), border_mode = "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode= "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(120, 5, 5, border_mode= "same"))

model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10)) # because 10 output classes
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# TRAIN
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adadelta")
nb_epoch = 2

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch, show_accuracy= True, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 0)
print("Test score: ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy: ", score[1])
```